# weird apache behaviour: error 500 if not owner of files

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, chown

My server runs on Centos 5 and I recently upgraded my php from 5.4.21 to 5.4.41 for some php_intl compability issues. (my problems stated then)

I usuall have all my httpdocs files in chown root:apache and chmod 755 (except the directory i need apache to write, like the symfony app/cache or others)

Recently (after update) my webpages went blank returning a silent (no message) 500 error.

Without changing the chown of root:apache I set a chmod 755 * -R and it worked again for 2 minutes or so and went back to this silent 500 error.

I then realized that the problem did not occure if i set the chown as apache:apache

This chmod 755 * -R that fixes the problem for two minutes is really strange though and i lost quite some time trying to understand if a file was switching back to an other chmod by itself or something but nop...

If you have any clue why this chmod would fix the problem for  a few minutes only.

Second thing (most important) why would apache not read my file in root:apache 755 as it clearly has the read permissions ?

a few details :

I run httpd via a "sudo httpd start"
in the config the User and Group for httpd is "apache"
my linux user apache is in the group apache
it worked ok before i updated the php version which is weird as apache confi does not seem to have changed.

Comment: This is CentOS, so I would suspect SELinux. `restorecond` would change back SELinux context if you changed it, but it sounds like you only modified permissions. First, check if SELinux is running in Enforcing mode with `/usr/sbin/getenforce`.  You should also look in Apache's error log, because any 500 error should be detailed there (in PHP, a silent 500 is known as the White Screen of Death). It may be fixable in code.

Comment: /usr/sbin/getenforce returns "disabled".
The weird thing is that nothing changed AND that the 500 (white screen of the death) did not come immediately but progressively on my different vhosts.

Comment: You'll need to watch Apache's error log to figure out what specifically the 500 error is.

Comment: No error for this specific white screen. 
Looked in /var/log/httpd/error_log as well as vhost/<the vhost>/statistics/logs

I tried to generate other 500 errors and i do have the log but for this specific one nop.

i'll check in my httpd config if there is differnciation of errors 500

Comment: If it is an Apache error, it must be logged somewhere. If it was a PHP error, it would be logged if php.ini specifies some value for `error_reporting` besides "off", and `log_errors` is on. Ensure in your php.ini that `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `log_errors = On`. You will need to restart Apache for that to take effect.

Comment: Tried that, nothing more than warning (there when it works also) and notices.

Ho, by the way important thing, my vhosts host wordpress multisites.
I tried deactivating plugins and all.

The weird thing is still that a simple chmod 755 makes it work for 1 to 3 minutes and then it stops working.
I saved ls -laR just after chmod and once it stops working to compare and see if any files changed at all but all stay the same (except the logs that fill up)

Comment: I don't know what Wordpress does with errors or error_reporting. Put it into debug mode to see if errors make it through to the screen or logs. Without knowing what caused the 500, it's going to be hard to figure out what to fix. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Yeah, i tried pretty much all the basic debugging.
Last recourse was stack exchange to maybe encounter someone who knew this weird behaviour.
"error 500 after 2 minutes" does not quite return targeted answers to my problem